# Git SSH public key fingerprint does not match with that on local machine

Tags: ssh, git

I’m trying to SSH into my github account. I added my public key to my github account and it showed the fingerprint as something like this

```
SHA256:aYqWu+zL3hIOWTEGvneI90fehVQt9kuGVN7ov8WlTk8
```

When I SSH to git, it reject me with

```
permission denied(publickey)
```

then I run SSH -v and see my client offered public key as

```
RSA SHA256:aYqWu+zL3hIOWTEGvneI90fehVQt9kuGVN7ov8WlTk8 macbookpro@MacBooks-MacBook-Pro.local
```

mine has extra username@host.

Can anyone help me to get rid of this.
Thanks in advance!

** EDIT **

My ouput with `ssh -v git@github.com`

```
OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/macbookpro/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/macbookpro/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/macbookpro/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/macbookpro/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-0913e7e1
debug1: no match: babeld-0913e7e1
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'dungtinhhd123'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/macbookpro/.ssh/known_hosts:17
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:aYqWu+zL3hIOWTEGvneI90fehVQt9kuGVN7ov8WlTk8 /Users/macbookpro/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
dungtinhhd123@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Where is the private key saved and how did you instruct the SSH client to use it?

Comment: It locates in the same folder with the public key, ````~/.ssh```` and I didn’t touch anything about instructing the SSH client to use it. I thought it was defaulted by SSH. Also I can successfully SSH to my localhost with  public key.

Comment: Whether the SSH client will use it by default depends on the file name. Defaults for the `IdentityFile` option vary between versions, but commonly include `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa` and `~/.ssh/id_ec25519`. Is your named `~/.ssh/id_rsa`?

Comment: Yes. It includes only ````~/.ssh/id_rsa````

Comment: Please try `ssh -v git@github.com` and [add the output to your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1638909/edit) in a code block.

Comment: I edited in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake. I should have `ssh -T git@github.com` instead of `ssh -T mygituser@github.com`

Answer (score 0):

> RSA SHA256:aYqWu...8WlTk8 macbookpro@MacBooks-MacBook-Pro.local

The "macbookpro@MacBooks-MacBook-Pro.local" part of the public key is just a comment. It doesn't matter. It's frequently filled in with the account which created the key, to help in identifying the key.

If you want to remove the comment, the file containing the public key is a text file. You can edit the file with a text editor and delete the comment portion.

Comment: I removed it and now my SSH client offering the same fingerprint except the comment part is replaced by the path where the key pair are located.

Answer (score 0):

Is the key loaded in the ssh-agent?

Do you see it when your run  `ssh-add -l`?

You can add it with a `ssh-aadd -K` on macOS this should put an entry into your keychain.